# Ask Ubuntu goodies anyone?

Tags: discussion

Here at UDS a lot of people of course wear Ubuntu T-Shirts, for very obvious reasons. Wouldn't it be awesome if we could have some nice Ask Ubuntu T-Shirts to give away as there are a large number of Ubuntu experts here (~600 attendees)?

Here's what the UDS one looks like:

[image]

And we could just pile on to the existing tshirt system:

[image]

T-Shirts, stickers and pens would be great to have, I'd definitely buy them and I'm sure more of our community would too.

What do you think about it?

02-07-12: There is nothing in the Stack Exchange shop yet. Is it still planned?

Comment: Who is the ugly guy on the first pic? :P

Comment: You Sir, lost my vote! :D

Comment: Bah, no vote can replace a good joke ;O

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We do have plans to print site-specific shirts and stickers in the works! Stay tuned to the Stack Exchange Blog for news on that.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange do [have a (beta) shop](http://shop.stackexchange.com/collections/all). At the moment however, there are no Ask Ubuntu specific items. Good idea though...